# Joomla module or component to be render on a blank page

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

I have developed a Joomla module that does provides a form, processes its post data, does some calculations and displays the results.

The module includes a button to print the results. I'm currently using JavaScript to open a new window, paste the relevant HTML and open the print dialog.

Instead of JavaScript I would prefer to provide a separate URL for the print view and simply open that in a _blank target. This would make the application work better for people using screen readers or not having JavaScript available.

Is there any way that I can tell Joomla to not render the template along with my module? I was thinking that creating a component fixes that issue, but had to find that components are rendered into the template, too...

BTW: I have Joomla 1.5.22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you want you have to add additional `tmpl=component` query string parameter to the request URL. This will disable template and module rendering.

Your URL will look something like this: `index.php?option=com_xxx&view=xxx&tmpl=component`

Since you are using Joomla 1.5 you can request `index2.php?option=com_xxx&view=xxx` and it will only render the component. Joomla 2.5 does not have `index2.php` so if you plan to migrate in future, don't use this option.

If you are using SEF then adding `?tmpl=component` at the end on URL does the trick.

---

To go a step deeper... in your template directory you have `component.php` file, that is the file that's being loaded by `tmpl` param. You can copy `component.php` to `my_component.php`, do necessary changes and load your custom component template with `index.php?option=com_xxx&view=xxx&tmpl=my_component`

Comment: Depending on the specific output needed I have a recollection of a &no_html=1 option too.

Comment: Great, now I can render a module in full page of screen by Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

The joomla way of doing it would be to set your output to "raw", see this tut:

http://www.katcode.com/displaying-raw-output-in-joomla-by-setting-format-in-the-component/

Comment: that's an option too but `format= raw` only returns component response without proper html wrapping. It's good to use in ajax calls, but not for displaying at frontend.